# getelementsbyclassname Excel vba - error on repeated calls

Tags: excel, getelementsbyclassname, vba

Morning,

I am having trouble with a webscrape from Excel, whereby getelementsbyclassname is failing to act on some objects, throwing up the "Object doesn't support this property or method" error.

The problem appears when the object I am feeding into getelementsbyclassname is itself the result of a getelementsbyclassname method.  I am not sure why, particularly as I can get the class name when acting on a larger object...

Here is a code extract

```
''''Boring Variables Declaration I've cut out''''

'Initialise IE
Dim IEApp As New InternetExplorer 
Set IEApp = New InternetExplorer 
IEApp.Visible = True 'JB

'Open page and wait for page to load
  IEApp.navigate ("http://www.anicewebsite.com")
  Do Until IEApp.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE And IEApp.Busy = False
    DoEvents
  Loop

Set HTMLdoc = IEApp.document
Set RefLocation = Sheets("INFO_DUMP").Range("LocationRefCell")
Set trElements = HTMLdoc.getElementsByClassName("basic-details")
For Each trElement In trElements
        'Select the LHS box and extract info
        Set tdElement = trElement.getElementsByClassName("tieredToggle")
        'write start/end locations
        '''''THIS NEXT LINE THROWS AN ERROR'''''
         Data_str = tdElement.getElementsByClassName("title").innerText
        '''''AS DOES'''''
        MyObject=tdElement.getElementsByClassName("title")
         RefLocation.Offset(1, 2).Value = Data_str 
Next 'close tr Loop
```

However, I can get the 'title' object via

```
For Each trElement In trElements
        Set MyObject=trElement.getElementsByClassName("title")
Next 'close tr Loop
```

so the error is, presumably, something about tdElement (a DispHTMLElement Collection), which I tried to attach an image of but I lack the reputation (see link at end of post)...

Many thanks for any help.

PS. the webpage is structured, roughly, with a 2-column table whose rows I isolate with "basic-details".  The first column is the "tiered toggle" and then the items I want are inner text in eg. "title".  I need to use tieredtoggle as objects in each column have repeated class names

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tyb6.png

Comment: `tdElement` is a collection,  you will have to loop through it as you are doing for the `trElements`

Comment: Oh you are an absolute star.  Completely correct - I need to loop to access the objects' properties. Thankyou

Seems a bit inelegant though, is there a way to select elements and then work on them directly without an object loop?  I even have to do it if getelementsbyclassname selects a single object...

Comment: If you always need to process the first element you can use this notation: `tdElement(0)` (first item in collection), or you can use getElementById() and provide the id of the first element. More info on [this Mozilla page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this to get the innertext.

```
Data_str = tdElement.getElementsByClassName("title")(0).innerText
```

Instead of ("title")(0) you can enter the index value where the element is present.